# How do I change the node view mode before rendering?

Tags: 8, nodes

I have a content type with a custom view mode. How do I make sure node always get rendered with my custom view mode?

What would be the right way to programmatically change the node view mode before rendering?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to make sure that a content type is *always* rendered with a custom view mode, use the following hook in a module. (I assume the module machine name is mymodule.)

*mymodule.module*

```
/**
 * Implements hook_entity_view_mode_alter().
 */
function mymodule_entity_view_mode_alter(&$view_mode, $entity, $context) {
  if ($entity->getEntityTypeId() == 'node' && $entity->bundle() == 'my_content_type') {
    $view_mode = 'my_custom_view_mode';
  }
}
```